# NSAttributedString - add writing direction for Arabic Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, right-to-left, nsmutableattributedstring

I have an html content that i want to show on UILabel.

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ 
NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} 
documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
return attrStr;
```

This works good for English Language (LTR semantic), but since i want to support arabic as well the above method keeps the attributed string LTR.
Inspite of using this code : `self.view.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;`

I've tried

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSWritingDirectionAttributeName value:@[@(NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft | NSWritingDirectionOverride)] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
return mutableAttributedString;
```

Still the same. Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope will helpful to you for **right side alignment!!**

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

NSDictionary *attr = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                   NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};

NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:attr documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                   value:paragraphStyle
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];
return attributedText;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift** version of @BuLB JoBs's answer:

```
let yourHTMLString = "" // your string
let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
]
guard let data = yourHTMLString.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString!
do {
    attributedText = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
} catch { return }

// This attribute fixes the alignment problem for Arabic language
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
paragraphStyle.alignment = .right
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was about text direction, but answer about alignment. Strange...

Recently got same issue, when language direction was incorrect for attributed string from html. Fixed with html attribute `dir="rtl"`.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp